# Weird normals in Blender, why? Imported textures from Substance

Tags: texturing, import, normals, texture-baking, normal-map

So this is how it appears in Substance:
[image]

Yet it looks like this once imported into Blender:
[image]

[image]

[image]

I made sure to export the normal map as OpenGL, the normal map is set to non-color data. Changing the strength makes everything worse. I don't know what it could be.

edit: it doesnt even happen in viewport shading mode, nor eevee, only happening in cycles
[image]

Comment: Can you also share the texture? And are you sure that normals are not inverted?

Comment: i usually see displacement nodes plugged to the material output's displacement socket.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p3WFqdk this is what happens when i try to invert the green channel and these are my normals. dont think theyre inverted

Comment: it is plugged into the material output's displacement socket.

Answer (score 1):

i forgot to turn on displacement and bump in cycles settings. this fixed it right up